# javascript regex : possible to have a range in the quantifier?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex to match / test IP addresses:

```
 /^(?!0)(?!.*\.$)((1?\d?\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)(\.|$)){4}/$
```

So far, so good.  Now, I have to create a utility that will test for parts of an ip address string like this:

```
10.10.10.10 //should pass
10.10.10    //should pass
123.23      //should also pass
```

I was hoping to recycle my existing code and just put something like {1-4} as the quantifier but so far, it's a no go.

Comment: On a sidenote, it would probably be better not to parse IPs as strings, but rather as numbers (see [this](https://github.com/indutny/node-ip), for example).

Comment: You meant to use `{1,4}` I think. See https://regex101.com/r/cEVc0Q/1